# Copy full text by partial keyword c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

In my Selenium webdriver, I search for text based on a certain keyword:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.PartialLinkText(stringKeywords))));
```

I would like to grab the full text I have found and save it into a string. How would I be able to do this? I found this somewhere, but it wont let me use it as a string because it is a IWebElement. Could it help me anyway?

```
IWebElement txtbox = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(stringKeywords));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are able to locate the webelement using [PartialLinkText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890), to extract the complete `innerText` you can use the `GetAttribute()` method as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(stringKeywords)).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string txt = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(stringKeywords)).Text;
```